# Are there Only Two different types of group structure of order 4??

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I learned in my Abstract Algebra class that there are only two forms of group structure of order 4.

One is

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+&0&1&2&3\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1\\
3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}

and Klein 4-group.

But I think of another form such that

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\bullet&1&2&3&4\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3\\
3 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 1\\
4 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 2
\end{array}

What is wrong on my structure? I think it may not satisfy associativity, but I cannot show it.

Is it really wrong? then how can I show that it is wrong?

or is it one of the forms of order 4?

Comment: both these groups are cyclic groups of order four and are hence isomorphic. The generator of your group is the element $3$ or $4$.

Comment: @ArunKumar 
Oh... I see... I thought it may be isomorphic to one of the two forms of order 4 structure, but I can't show... I should have applied the concept of generator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the cyclic group : take the bijection $1\mapsto 0$, $2\mapsto 2$, $3\mapsto 1$ and $4\mapsto 3$.